# Is there a way to change the preferred base address of a dll once it's compiled?

Tags: winapi, dll, relocation

I'd like to modify the base address of a few compiled dlls I'm using to move them out of the middle of the virtual space and help with big allocations. Anybody knows of a tool to do that? If it's doable in the loader it seems it would be possible do to it permanently in the dll file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a tool ReBase.exe which comes with Visual Studio which can change the preferred load address of a DLL. The loader is always capable of changing this at run time, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the base address as a linker option in Visual Studio:

Project Properties | Configuration Properties | Linker | Advanced | Base Address

(Assuming a C++ project.)